# Why my postgis not use index on geometry field?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgis

postgresql 9.5 + postgis 2.2 on windows.
I firstly create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE points (
  id   SERIAL,
  ad   CHAR(40),
  name VARCHAR(200)
);
```

then, add a geometry field 'geom':

```
select addgeometrycolumn('points', 'geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
```

and create gist index on it:

```
CREATE INDEX points_index_geom ON points USING GIST (geom);
```

then, I insert about 1,000,000 points into the table.

I want to query all points that within given distance from given point.
this is my sql code:

```
SELECT st_astext(geom) as location FROM points
WHERE st_distance_sphere(
     st_geomfromtext('POINT(121.33 31.55)', 4326),
     geom) < 6000;
```

the result is what I want, but it is too slow.
when I `explain analyze verbose` on this code, I found it dose not use points_index_geom (explain shows seq scan and no index).

So i want to know why it dose not use index, and how should i improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expect `ST_Distance_Sphere()` to use an index on this query. You are doing a calculation on the contents of the geom field and then you are doing a comparison on the calculation result. Databases may not use an index in such a scenario unless you have a function index that does pretty much the same calculation as in your query.

The correct way to find locations with in a given distance from some point is to use [`ST_DWithin`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

> ST_DWithin — Returns true if the geometries are within the specified
>   distance of one another. For geometry units are in those of spatial
>   reference and For geography units are in meters and measurement is
>   defaulted to use_spheroid=true (measure around spheroid), for faster
>   check, use_spheroid=false to measure along sphere.

and

> This function call will automatically include a bounding box
>   comparison that will make use of any indexes that are available on the
>   geometries.

Comment: i have try st_dwithin(), my source data are many points represent by (longitude, latitude), i use geometry(point, 4326) as my geom field. then, my sql code is :SELECT id, name, st_astext(geom)
from geom_points where st_dwithin(geom, st_geomfromtext('POINT(121.33 31.55)', 4326), 6000); but it also dose not use gist index on geom.

Comment: and another question is, can i use geometry type if my given_distance using meter as unit(not geometry units)?

Comment: isn't 6000 in your query actuallly 6000 degrees because you are using geom. So again it's right that the db shouldn't use an index. It needs to find every thing

Comment: i wrote my above comment before your second comment came through. Approximately 1 degree = 111km

Comment: thank you very much. finally i choose GEOGRAPHY so that i can use meters (not degree) as distance. and functions (st_DWithin, st_Covers...) on geography type really use index on geography field