# MySql not using spatial index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have spatial column and spatial index for it. When I making query, I see that MySql not using that index. Table has 10k records. Why?

`schema.rb`

```
create_table "homes_raw", id: :string, limit: 22, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.geometry "location", limit: {:type=>"point", :srid=>0}, null: false
   t.index ["location"], name: "location_spatial", type: :spatial
end
```

Performing query with EXPLAIN

````
EXPLAIN for: SELECT `homes_raw`.* FROM `homes_raw` WHERE (ST_Distance_Sphere(
            ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(location), 0), POINT(60.41217340143263, 64.48856982983708)
            ) <= 100000)
    ```

[EPLAIN result][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRDGS.png
````

Comment: Pls share the query written in active record dsl.

Comment: Did you do benchmarks? Like, maybe the explain is just not showing that it's using the index while it still is using it when performing a query.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this particular area (MySQL geo queries), so I did a quick google search. Did you check these two resources? * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968349/why-my-postgis-not-use-index-on-geometry-field                 * https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html

Comment: As described in Fazes first link, you cannot use an index on a calculated result; you have an index on `location`, but are evaluating on `ST_GeomFromText(st_astext(location), 0)`. It's not entirely clear why you do this, so maybe add sample data and/or explain that conversion or just try to use "location" directly.

Comment: Check [Mysql Spatial index unused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388990/mysql-spatial-index-unused).